# How to use a type defined using typeof in an array?

Tags: typescript

In a (React) class I have defined a local identifier to access another type (used by this class):

```js
export class Dropdown extends Component<IDropdownProperties, IDropdownState> {

    public static Item = DropdownItem;

}
```

I can now use that to create a drop down item:

```
    const item = <Dropdown.Item id="id />
```

Now I want to have an array of items:

```
    const items: Array<Dropdown.Item> = [];
```

With that Typescript shows the error:

> error TS2702: 'Dropdown' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

What is the correct syntax to use `Dropdown.Item` as an array element type?

Note: I do not explicitly use `typeof` here (and when I do, also the single item creation is invalid), but Visual Studio Code shows me:

[image]

which is why I'm asking about `typeof`. But of course, other solutions are welcome too, if I can keep that `Dropdown.Item` syntax. I could just switch to use `DropdownItem` instead, but that's not what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Dropdown.Item` refers to the component type, not instance type, which is why simply using `typeof` won't work. You need to wrap it in `InstanceType`.

Simplified example (using classes instead of React components):

```
class DropdownItem {

}

class Dropdown {
  public static Item = DropdownItem
}

const items: Array<InstanceType<typeof Dropdown.Item>> = [new Dropdown.Item()]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBOB7ADgE0QdwHYEkAuApgLbQDeAUOQL6WiQwIrrZnnTTICuARiAJbBoEPGDwDo%20YtAC8cJGky5CRarURZh0PsogAuaAEF48MAE8APDg0iswAgBVTyAubxOCiAGZymigHSSRAB8QTLQANpYBBg%20CtgBygAUAJQAuuRAA)

Comment: OK, your example compiles, however, it doesn't work with React components (there's a complain about missing properties). The React part isn't part of the question, so I'm going to accept this answer, unless someone else provides one that also works with React.

Comment: @MikeLischke In case of React components you simply need to replace `InstanceType` with `ReactElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to create an array of created react elements:

```js
const items: Array<React.ReactElement<(typeof Dropdown)['Item']>>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgEkARHMAEwgHcA7ABVaSxgSAM5wAvIiRpobADwiYUYNwDmAGjiLlagHxVa9Zqw48AyjBQx6k5DKjztKjVqXP9lcmgA2KEWJYIdi5uBms8JAAPa242MWR0GAA6AGFcSG4kbngAbwoKAF988ijIWDgfPwCTELgomLipRNT0iEzsuWMg0z4BIVFNLuDzS2tdODzPOGm4MABXACNvYDRXKxXGcIk4QOHQ8IBuYqLPChluRThgcJEALjgAQSgoFGo5BIwkj5gAUW8kEBZGByAAUNDoEEwOxqPAAlABtfBhAH4AC6unGknhFBmcDkux6SWReAA9Lp1DiZviYdwiVsyRRURQgA)

---

#### Edit:

If you have access to the type `DropdownItem` (e.g. begin exported) where the list `items` is defined you can describe it as

```js
const items: React.ReactElement<DropdownItem>[] = []
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=49#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgEkARHMAEwgHcA7ABVaSxgSAM5wAvIiRpobADwiYUYNwDmAGjiLlagHxVa9Zqw48AyjBQx6k5DKjztKjVqXP9lcmgA2KEWJYIdi5uBms8JAAPa242MWR0GAA6AGFcSG4kbngAbwoKAF988ijIWDgfPwCTELgomLipRNT0iEzsuWMg0z4BIVFNLuDzS2tdODzPOGm4MABXACNvYDRXKxXGcIk4QOHQ8IBuYqLPChluRThgcJEALjgAQSgoFGo5BIwkj5gAUW8kEBZGByAAUNDoEEwOxqPAAlABtfBhAH4AC6unGknhFBmcDkux6SWReAA9Lp1DiZviYdwiVsyRRUcUzm1LtcASIAEz3b5fYi-f6AjoEkLE3Tw1HbbHkXHU7ohOkAuBkikyqkiniK0keJnkIA)

---

[and here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-pond-1rrmu?file=/src/Dropdown/Dropdown.tsx) you can check the following approach with functional components

Comment: Hmm, that's a way, right, though not so well readable.

Comment: @MikeLischke Then you can export the type form your component and define it as `React.ReactElement<DropdownItem>[]` it's indeed cleaner